# How to use RemoteViews' addView() appropriately

Tags: android, remoteview

I've seen other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233930/8290499) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040066) that explain the correct way to add a new View to a RemoteViews object. In the first link, it is specified that there should be a nested LinearLayout inside an outer LinearLayout such that the inner layout is referenced in the addView method, e.g. `addView(innerLayoutID, view)`.

Why reference the inner layout instead of the outer one? Does addView not work with the outer layout or is this just personal opinion?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the answer in the first link was generally correct but I couldn't run it exactly as it was posted, so I needed more details in order to get it running in my project. I posted my code below for future reference.

Note that a very important that wasn't specified in the other threads is that `rv.addView()` required the same layout as specified in the `rv` object; that is to say, I couldn't have a `LinearLayout` nested within another `LinearLayout` and then reference the inner `LinearLayout`. I had to reference the outer one since that is what was referenced in the parent `rv` instance.

My `onUpdate()` is specific to Samsung Look's Edge Panel API, but the general format is the same:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, SlookCocktailManager manager, int[] cocktailIds) {
    //Parent RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_view);
    for (int i = 0; i < someObjectArray.length; i++) {
        //Create new remote view using the xml file that represents a list entry
        RemoteViews listEntryLayout = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_entry);
        //Set the text of the TextView that is inside the above specified listEntryLayout RemoteViews
        listEntryLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.stock_text, someObjectArray[i].getName());
        //Add the new remote view to the parent/containing Layout object
        rv.addView(R.id.main_layout, listEntryLayout);
    }
    //standard update
    if (cocktailIds != null) {
        for (int id : cocktailIds) {
            manager.updateCocktail(id, rv);
        }
    }
}
```

main_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAccessibility="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

list_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/stock_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```